# ¿Cómo seleccionar una constante distinta una vez se inicializa el programa?

Tags: c, constantes

Soy algo nuevo en programación con `C`, de hecho estoy en mi primer año de universidad y nos han encargado hacer un programa, "juego del ahorcado", modularizado y el programa debe tener 10 palabras definidas como constantes, tengo todo listo, pero al momento de seleccionar una constante, no tengo idea de como hacerlo, es decir, puedo hacer que el programa tenga predefinida la constante `P1` donde es mi primera palabra pero el juego debe seleccionar una distinta (en lo posible `p1`, luego `p2` y así) y mostrarla al perder, ganar y posteriormente cambiarla por la siguiente al poner "volver a jugar" pero me ha pillado.

```
 define p1 "ORNITORRINCO" 
 define p2 "PARALELEPIPEDO" 
 define p3 "TABLETA" 
 define p4 "CAMARA" 
 define p5 "JUEGOS" 
 define p6 "RATON" 
 define p7 "IMPOSIBLE" 
 define p8 "GRANDES" 
 define p9 "COMPUTADORA" 
 define p10 "PROGRAMADOR" 

 int intentos=6, fallos=0, i=0, bien=0, l=0, largo, cc=0, numl, sp, e=0;  
 char letra, Lingresadas[26], vj='s', frase[26], palabra[26];  

 void interfazinicial (){ 
    TituloJuego(); 
    printf ("\n"); 
    printf ("Tienes %d intentos \n", intentos); 
    SinAhorcado(); 
 }
 void Largopalabra(){ 
    largo=strlen(p1);  
    palabra[largo]; 
    strcpy(palabra, p1);  
    frase[largo]; //  
    memset(frase,'-',largo);  
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de que el programa vaya seleccionando las constantes a medida que avanza?

Comment: ¿Tienes código hecho? Sería útil si nos muestras un poco.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Este no es un foro tradicional, te dejo algunos consejos sobre como realizar tus preguntas. Puedes empezar realizando el [tour] y leer [ask] para entender un poco la dinámica del sitio y el tipo de preguntas que se esperan. Luego podrías leer [mcve]. Si tus preguntas están formuladas de esa manera, seguramente mucha gente podrá ayudarte, de lo contrario serán cerradas rapidamente. Saludos!

Comment: @NaCl ahí edité y puse una pequeña parte del codigo

Comment: @cventu Gracias! ahí voy a leer y editar acorde a lo que piden

Comment: @JorgeHinojosa Puedes darle formato a tu pregunta utilizando markdown en el editor, porfavor coloca el código en tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es utilizar un vector de cadenas de caracteres en lugar de constantes para tus palabras secretas.

Sería algo asi:

```
char * palabras[10] = {"ORNITORRINCO", 
                       "PARALELEPIPEDO",
                       "TABLETA", 
                       "CAMARA", 
                       "JUEGOS", 
                       "RATON", 
                       "IMPOSIBLE", 
                       "GRANDES", 
                       "COMPUTADORA", 
                       "PROGRAMADOR"};
```

De esa manera, habrás creado un array en el cual palabras[0] corresponde a ORNITORRINCO, palabras[1] a PARALELEPIDO y asi sucesivamente hasta palabras[9] correspondiente a PROGRAMADOR

### EDITO: (resolución usando constantes)

```
 #define P1 "ORNITORRINCO" 
 #define P2 "PARALELEPIPEDO" 
 #define P3 "TABLETA" 
 #define P4 "CAMARA" 
 #define P5 "JUEGOS" 
 #define P6 "RATON" 
 #define P7 "IMPOSIBLE" 
 #define P8 "GRANDES" 
 #define P9 "COMPUTADORA" 
 #define P10 "PROGRAMADOR" 

int numero_de_juego;
char palabra_clave[100];

switch (numero_de_juego)
{
    case 1:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P1);
              break;

    case 2:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P2);
              break;

    case 3:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P3);
              break;

    case 4:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P4);
              break;

    case 5:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P5);
              break;

    case 6:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P6);
              break;

    case 7:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P7);
              break;

    case 8:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P8);
              break;

    case 9:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P9);
              break;

    case 10:
              strcpy(palabra_clave,P10);
              break;
}
```

Cada vez que quieras cambiar la palabra, solo debes modificar el valor de la variable numero_de_juego. Luego podrías llamar a tu función que se encarga de realizar el juego en si mismo y pasarle como argumento la cadena de caracteres llamada palabra_clave.

Comment: Las indicaciones del trabajo son en constantes pero estuve buscando la forma y creo que con un Switch, otra variable que sea el "numero de juego", un arreglo donde almacenar esa constante y así inicializar el juego, por ahora estoy mentalizando bien la idea para llevarla a cabo

Comment: Entiendo. No lo hice con constantes porque de esta manera el código sería mas simple, pero si necesitas hacerlo si o si de esa manera no hay problema, ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente y luego en caso de que no exista un case 11, pongo default para inicializar en 1 nuevamente "numero_de_juego.
Muchas gracias! me ha servido bastante